# Parsing Javascript files with phpDocumentor

Tags: javascript, parsing, phpdoc

I've been playing with phpDocumentor recently and found it quite suitable for my needs. I'm largely working with PHP/HTML/JS/CSS codebases and would like phpDocumentor to parse my Javascript (and perhaps CSS) in order to keep it all together.

I've managed to get phpdoc to parse javascript files contained throughout the codebase - however it rejects the page-level docblock - which results in it rejecting the various tags (see below). I've found that by adding in a PHP open tag (with a JavaScript comment before it) to the top of the JavaScript file, I can get it to parse it just like a PHP file.

```
// <?php
/**
 * phpdoc goes here
 * @package
 * @todo
 *   - Todo 1
 *   - Todo 2
 */
function javascript(goes, here) {
}
```

I can think of a problem occurring should the webserver be setup to server .js files through PHP. Are there any other problems anyone can think of? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as potential problems, one that comes to mind is that since you're "tricking" phpDocumentor into parsing the docblock *and the JS code*, you're implicitly counting on the PHP tokenizer (which is how phpDocumentor parses PHP code internally) to successfully read your JS code and treat it as PHP code.  When this succeeds, I think you'll have good results... your simple function example should probably succeed.  However, if your JS code will *not* parse successfully as PHP code, then I bet phpDocumentor won't see it as a documentable code element, and therefore it will not appear in your docs.

Answer (score 8):

I think it's a bit naive assumption to think there is no similar tool for JavaScript.

There is a tool called [JSDoc](http://jsdoc.sourceforge.net/) which is basically the same as phpdoc, but for JavaScript.

---

**Update Friday, May 1, 2015:-**

It seems like that the new project link is:-

https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc

Comment: I didn't know JSDoc either. I see @ncatnow's point, though: Generating the documentation in one place and on layout, instead of having to use two solutions with two setups in two different languages, would be lovley. At least for solely functional Javascript this should be possible, shouldn't it? –

Comment: Perhaps try Doxygen? It's similar to PHPDoc, supports PHP, and afaik JavaScript too. Haven't used it myself though.

Comment: @Jani Hartikainen: I think it's a bit naive assumption to think that I have not already researched this. I looked at JSDoc but it was a bit over the top when all I want is to include the few JS files in the current set of docs, with some simple 'phpdoc', which would allow me to set some todo items, package it, and so forth.

Pekka is right on the money. As I said - I already have this working from a document generation point of view. I'm interested to know if someone else has done this before, and made it work in a more l33t way than me.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for the same thing. I found JSDoc and PhpDocumentor but considering the fact that 1 (ONE) application as a "Whole" contains both PHP and JavaScript making the base of the application I would prefer 1 approach to documenting the projects. It really sucks to have 2 documentation sets, 1 for php and 1 for JavaScript. That ole @see or inline @link does not work in the case of, @see this other function/class in this other langauge, via some other documentation program.... get my drift?